# Angularjs slice nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to slice content of block with nested `ng-repeat` to show page by page. The content is `overflow viewport`.

Does anyone know how can I do it?

**HTML**

```
<li class="outer-ng-repeat" ng-repeat="epgDate in epgDates">
    <h3></h3>
    <div class="inner-container" >
        <div class="nested-ng-repeat"
            ng-repeat="epg in epgDate.epg">
            <div class="telecast__name">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I want to slice content by pages based on some condition, I've tried `slice(0, 10)` but in my case it is not a solution. I need to attach to, maybe, `viewport height` or something, I don't know, help please.